# Using pjsip in daemon mode with python twisted

Tags: python, twisted, sip, daemon, pjsip

I am trying to run simple pjsip application in daemon mode. I have combined this library with python twisted. Script works fine when I run it in shell & can make call. But when I use it with twisted's Application framework, I get following error.

```
Object: {Account <sip:192.168.0.200:5060>}, operation=make_call(), error=Unknown error from audio driver (PJMEDIA_EAUD_SYSERR)
```

Most of example applications from documents do not run in daemon mode - [pjsip examples](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial).

Looks like even pjsua doesn't run in background - [pjsua](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm)

I am wondering, does it work in background. I am not getting exactly what "Unknown error" meant to. Is there any better way to debug ?

Architecture of my application is as follows -

1. Start pjsip lib, initiate pjsip lib, create transport & create userless account.
2. Create UDP protocol which listens for incoming requests.
3. Once app gets request, it makes calls to particular sip uri.

Everything goes well when I run app with [listenUDP](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/16.3.1/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorUDP.listenUDP.html) & `reactor.run()` but when I tries with typical twisted application setup - [twistd](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/core/howto/application.html#auto4)( either `listenUPD` or `UDPServer`) above error pops up.

Am I doing anything wrong ? Any info will be welcomed.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue resolved after I set sound devices.